# Assign complex command result to variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a fairly simple bash shell scripting problem.

I want to `sed` a piece of text and then assign the result of the `sed` to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash
MOD_DATE=echo $(date) | sed 's/\ /_/g'
echo $MOD_DATE // should show date with spaces replaced with underscores.
```

I have tried the above and it doesn't work. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To collect the output in stdout into a variable, use a [command substitution](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/bashref/CommandSubstitution.html):

```
MOD_DATE=`echo $(date) | sed 's/\ /_/g'`
#        ^                             ^
```

or

```
MOD_DATE=$(echo $(date) | sed 's/\ /_/g')
#        ^^                             ^
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this can help:

```
mod_date = "$(date +"%d_%m_%Y")"
echo "$mod_date"
```

Comment: You can't put spaces around the `=`.

Comment: better test before posting :)